# What lines should I put so that when I write something the Discord bot responds in a way that I want (discord.py)?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I don't know what lines should I put to make the bots reply me to a message WITHOUT A PREFIX, like I say "Hi", and he says "Hello!"... can you help me?

That's my code

```
import discord
import os
import requests
import json
import random
from web import keep_alive
from discord.ext import commands

def command_prefix(bot, message):
    if message.guild is None:
        return ''
    else:
        return '\\'

client=commands.Bot(command_prefix=command_prefix,case_insensitive=True)
client.remove_command('help')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching,name='Having fun in 4 SERVER - DM Tomm#7615 to get the my invite link'))
  print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

async def on_message(self, message):
    if message.content.startswith('here come dat boi'):
        await self.send_message(message.channel, 'o shit waddup!')

client.run('TOKEN')
```

All answers are appreciated.

Have a good day friend!

**Tomm**

Comment: What is the current output? What prefix? Does on_message not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version is this?... For rewrite its this:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('here come dat boi'):
        return await message.channel.send('o shit waddup!')
    elif message.content.startswith('Hi'):
        return await message.channel.send('Hello')
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just change this:

```py
async def on_message(self, message):
    if message.content.startswith('here come dat boi'):
        await self.send_message(message.channel, 'o shit waddup!')
```

To this:

```py
async def on_message(self, message):
    if message.content == 'Hi':
        await self.send_message(message.channel, 'Hello!')
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! Sadly it's not working... I'm trying with another method

Comment: Why is it not working? Any error message?

Comment: self.send_message is old... ctx is the right one